# Decorator that includes celery task with attributes

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm working on a Django project with several apps, each of them have their set of tasks and it works pretty fine. But, in general, the set of tasks of each app use the same attributes for rate limiting, retry, etc. I was trying to create a decorator that would have all those common attributes and set the target function as a task.

So, I have this in my `example/tasks.py`:

```py
from celery import current_app


@current_app.task(
    queue='example_queue',
    max_retries=3,
    rate_limit='10/s')
def example_task_1():
    ...

@current_app.task(
    queue='example_queue',
    max_retries=3,
    rate_limit='10/s')
def example_task_2():
    ...
```

I'm trying something like:

```py
from celery import current_app, Task


class ExampleTask(Task):

    def __init__(self, task, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.task = task

    def run(self):
        self.task()


def example_decorator_task(func):

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return ExampleTask(func).delay(
            queue='example_queue',
            max_retries=3,
            rate_limit='10/s')

@example_decorator_task
def example_task_1():
    ...

@example_decorator_task
def example_task_2():
    ...
```

I got this to work, but the tasks will not work as usual by calling `example_task_1.delay(...)`, since is being executed inside the wrapper.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use `apply_async` instead of `delay`, and your decorator should change to this:

```py
def decorator(function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return function.apply_async(args=[*args], kwargs={**kwargs}, **{
            'queue': 'example_queue',
            'max_retries': 3,
            'rate_limit': '10/s'
        })
    return wrapper
```

for more detail:

- [apply_async](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.apply_async)
- [delay](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.delay)

Comment: Ok, cool :) but with this I would still need to use both: `@current_app.task` and `@decorator`, is it possible to make `decorator` have the same functionality as `@current_app.task` + the settings I want?

Comment: Sorry for the answer, I didn't catch the question at the start, so I don't have an exact answer, but calling the `celeryapp.task` decorator and passing the function on it, and calling the `apply_async` on the returned value might work.

Answer (score 0):

Parametrized decorators convert into parameter-less decorators when you pass the parameters, but without applying them to a function. So you can create a new decorator by storing the result into a variable, which you can then apply to the various task functions. See:

```
from celery import current_app

rate_limited_task = current_app.task(
    queue='example_queue',
    max_retries=3,
    rate_limit='10/s'
)

@rate_limited_task
def example_task_1():
    ...

@rate_limited_task
def example_task_2():
    ...
```